# Migration process linux consuming high CPU time

Tags: cpu-usage

```
ps aux

USER PID %CPU %MEM VSZ RSS TTY STAT START TIME COMMAND

root 12 2367 0.0 0 0 ? S Dec12 73367:02 [migration/1]
```

Migration/1 is consuming high CPU time while being in "S" state.

What does this mean? Is there something I could/should do about it?

Comment: What is the process? How did it start? What it is part of? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @DopeGhoti I think that's _the question_.

Comment: What kernel is this on?

Comment: Related - [What is the 'migration" process](https://superuser.com/questions/440906/what-is-the-migration-process)

Comment: Related - [Kernel Processes Periodically Eating CPU During High Load](https://serverfault.com/questions/674685/kernel-processes-periodically-eating-cpu-during-high-load)

Answer (score 2):

See [this question and answer over on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/674685/kernel-processes-periodically-eating-cpu-during-high-load) (the site for sysadmins).

`migration` is part of the kernel, and is a thread that is responsible for moving processes to another CPU to balance out the workload. It shouldn't take a lot of CPU itself — apparently, from the other answer, there was a bug in kernels before 3.6.11 which might be the problem. Or, this may be a symptom of overloaded swap.

Comment: The version is 4.4.0-63-generic. I read somewhere to modify the swap value too and I changed it to 0. It still shows high CPU time. I ran taskset to see which core it was running on and tried to see if there were any processes running on that CPU that were in state "D" or "R" but nothing :( I really dont know what to do :(